# How to save Docker files (images, container) in specific driver?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am using Docker for Windows 19.03.13 on Windows 10 x64 version 2004. (I seen this type of question 3 years ago, and at this time, many thing changed.)

How to save Docker files (images, container) in specific driver? My `C:\` is nearly full now.

This is my system information

```
C:\Users\donhuvy>docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration  0.1.18
 Version:           19.03.13
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        4484c46d9d
 Built:             Wed Sep 16 17:00:27 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.13
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       4484c46d9d
  Built:            Wed Sep 16 17:07:04 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.3.7
  GitCommit:        8fba4e9a7d01810a393d5d25a3621dc101981175
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683

C:\Users\donhuvy>docker system df
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              9                   5                   2.95GB              1.245GB (42%)
Containers          14                  0                   39.01kB             39.01kB (100%)
Local Volumes       2                   2                   48.77MB             0B (0%)
Build Cache         12                  0                   32.56kB             32.56kB

C:\Users\donhuvy>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a different setup if you're running Docker Desktop or Docker Toolbox, but the two questions linked above cover the two cases.

Comment: Maybe `%APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json`